# Why does my external monitor brightness increase on 144 Hz?

Tags: mac, display, displayport

I have an external display connected via DisplayPort.  With 144 Hz refresh rate selected the image brightness goes up by quite a bit.  Any other refresh rate (even 120) will show a darker, less washed out image.  The actual monitor OSD settings are not changed when this happens.  Anyone know why this would happen and if it can be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was related to another issue I had, caused by a monitor with defective timing.  I got a replacement which solves this.